# How can I show that the $\lim_{x\to0^+}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist using sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to show that $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x>0$ does not have a limit as $x\to0^+$, which makes sense since it oscillates, but I don't know how to show it using sequences.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** There are infinitely many $z_n$ such that $\sin(z_n)=1$, and infinitely many $y_n$ such that $\sin(y_n)=-1$, such that $z_n\to\infty$ and $y_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.